# Accessing messageQueue from anonymous web service

Tags: c#, web-services, message-queue, anonymous

I have a public message queue with full permissions to everyone, that I attempt to access from an anonymous web service.

1. Method `MessageQueue.Exists` -> Returns false all the time. If the queue is public and everyone has permissions, why can't I find it?
2. I changed my code to look like this:

   MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(name);

   return queue.Peek(expireInterval);

But this throws exception that the queue does not exist or I have no permissions to access it.

The web service must remain anonymous, why isn't it enough to give permissions on the queue?

I even tried giving full control to ANONYMOUS account, nada.

Someone please explain this voodoo to me, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found a similar question asked in this site that was answered with changing the queue path from ".\QueueName" to "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:.\QueueName".

This indeed helped, although I couldn't find why.
I then found this article: 
http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/02/msmq_sending_message_to_remote.html
which explains that accessing a MSMQ remotely requires using FormatName syntax.

I still don't understand why this works when the WS is running under integrated security.